# Backspace key in keyboard while opening a web page

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the link between a web page and keyboard Backspace key ? when v press backspace key while opening a web page and it ll move the previous page. y it so ? during some security how is it possible to work good from user side ?

Answer (score 2):

The backspace key is a keyboard shortcut for browser Back button.  Unless a textbox or embedded object has the focus, pressing the backspace key will function the same as clicking the Back button.

Comment: It's really entertaining to be editing something and accidentally click outside the textbox with the touchpad, hit backspace, and lose the text.

Comment: @MarkSowul: That's one of the reasons I use [Lazarus](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) (Firefox, Chrome, Safari).